# How to use CallScreeningService in android to reject the incoming call

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, android-permissions, callscreeningservice

I am trying to add CallScreeningService in my android application(targetSdkVersion 29) without making my app a caller app. I follow all the instructions but still not getting it properly OR missing something there.
Here is my code:

```
public class CallAppService extends CallScreeningService {
    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
        Log.e("CallBouncer", "Call screening service triggered");
        respondToCall(callDetails, new CallScreeningService.CallResponse.Builder().setDisallowCall(true).setRejectCall(true).build());
    }
}

<service android:name="com.myapp.service.CallAppService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Added following permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
```

But still that this service is not invoking when I do a call. Is there anything that I am missing? I also see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57000907/8316275) but not getting the idea that why we need a ServiceConnection as it is not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer to another question (get incoming number by `CallScreeningService`):

[I want to get hold of phone number Programmatically as the phone is ringing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711455/i-want-to-get-hold-of-phone-number-programmatically-as-the-phone-is-ringing-in-a/77762680#77762680)

And the only difference is that you should use your own `callResponse` instead to reject it.